# What options are available to create a vacuum with hydraulics?

Tags: hydraulics, vacuum

What options are available to create a vacuum using hydraulics?  I am working on constructing a small planter which needs a vacuum to operate.

Planters operate best at a pressure of 10 PSI.  I think flow is around 30-50 gallon per minute range per row unit. This design has 2 row units.

Comment: Are you referring to suction (moving fluids from behind the pump) or operating within a vacuum? i.e. http://www.amazon.com/3B-Scientific-U21851-Vacuum-Bell/dp/B005LY43BW

Comment: I'm thinking suction.

Comment: There are a lot of options for suction pumps but there is little that can be done without you telling us what your situation or plan is.

Comment: It would help to answer this question if you could elaborate on a few things ie :

Comment: Added pressure and best guess at flow rate.

Answer (score 1):

There are devices called aspirators which use a stream of water to create a vacuum by the venturi effect. They basically consist of a T connector with the suction inlet at right angles to the the water flow. Across the joint the water flow is constricted, which accelerates it, dropping the pressure and creating suction.

The vacuum pressure generated is fairly modest and they use quite a lot of water but they are extremely simple. But if you need the vacuum to do a significant amount of work this may not be adequate. However is you can include a source of compressed air in your system then much higher pressures are possible using the same principal.

What is practical really depends on the context, for example whether you want discrete pulses eg to pick something up with a suction cup or a continuous suction more like a vacuum cleaner. In many cases a self contained electric vacuum pump will be the most convenient solution.

Obviously there is ultimately the possibility to operate a vacuum pump or piston via a hydraulic motor or actuator.

Comment: Up voted because this is an option. I'm hoping to generate a range of options so I can pick the best for this design.